# Keystore SHA1 doesn't match with fingerprint certificate

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore, google-play-developer-api, signed-apk

I had generated signed apk and uploaded before 3 months. Now I edit project and re-generate signed apk with previous keystore.jks. But google has rejected mentioning different certificate fingerprint. I am sure I have developed only one application in this laptop and there is only one jks file. I had uploaded apk using this keystore. I have keystore backup, previous signed apk and project file, any idea how to solve this problem. In addition, My signingReport shows debug.keystore instead of my real file name(samplekey.jks in which keystore has been stored) But in other's tutorial I found real keystore file name(.jks format)

[image]

It ruined my 2 days and Now I am clueless. One forum advised me to change computer clock and upload it. But I think it is not right way. Is there any idea to copy keystore previous apk to currently developed apk or any solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good reason to opt into [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423).

It looks from the error message that you are registered with Google Play App signing (as it is asking about your upload certificate). You can contact Google Play developer support and they can move you to a new upload certificate. See the section "lost or compromised private keys" in [the help docs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) for what to do.

Comment: Apps with APK doesn't need to use Google Play App Signing, while apps with Android App Bundles is mandatory to use Google App Signing.

Comment: I don't understand why that is relevant to the question or this answer?